# How do I copy/clone a struct that derives neither?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to do some game programming with Piston, but i'm struggling with `opengl_graphics::Texture`, since it does not derive `Copy` or `Clone`.

```
extern crate piston_window;
extern crate piston;
extern crate graphics;
extern crate opengl_graphics;

use opengl_graphics::Texture as Tex;
use piston_window::*;
use std::path::Path;
use opengl_graphics::GlGraphics;

#[derive(PartialEq)]
enum ObjectType {
    Blocking,
    Passing,
}
struct Object {
    sprite: Tex,
    obj_type: ObjectType,
    position: Position,
}
struct Game {
    gl: GlGraphics,
    images: Vec<Object>,
    player: Player,
}
struct Player {
    sprite: Tex,
    position: Position,
}
struct Position {
    x: i32,
    y: i32,
}

impl Game {
    fn render(&mut self, args: &RenderArgs) {

        let iter = self.images.iter();
        let player = &self.player;
        self.gl.draw(args.viewport(), |c, g| {

            clear([1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], g);

            for img in iter {
                let pos = img.get_position();
                let transform = c.transform.trans(((pos.x * 64)) as f64, ((pos.y * 64)) as f64);
                image(img.get_sprite(), transform, g);
            }
            image(player.get_sprite(),
                  c.transform.trans((player.get_position().x * 64) as f64,
                                    (player.get_position().y * 64) as f64),
                  g);
        });
    }


    fn update(&mut self, args: &UpdateArgs) {}
}
```

The main game loop:

```
fn main() {
    let (width, height) = (64*10, 64*10);
    let opengl = OpenGL::V3_2;
    let mut window: PistonWindow =
        WindowSettings::new("piston", (width, height))
        .exit_on_esc(true)
        .opengl(opengl)
        .build()
        .unwrap();
    window.hide();
    println!("Loading...");
    let mut player = Player { sprite: Tex::from_path(&Path::new(
                            "./assets/player_n.png")).unwrap(),
                            position: Position { x: 3, y: 3 },
    };

    let mut game = Game {
        gl: GlGraphics::new(opengl),
        images: Vec::new(),
        player: player,
    };

    for i in 0..10 {
        for j in 0..10 {
            if i == 0 || i == 9 || j == 0 || j == 9 {
                let obj = Object { sprite: Tex::from_path(&Path::new(
                        "./assets/wall.png")).unwrap(),                                                 
                    obj_type: ObjectType::Blocking,
                        position: Position { x: i, y: j },
                };
                game.images.push(obj);

            } else {
                let obj = Object { sprite: Tex::from_path(&Path::new(
                        "./assets/floor.png")).unwrap(),                                                
                    obj_type: ObjectType::Passing,
                        position: Position { x: i, y: j },
                };
                game.images.push(obj);
            }
        }
    }
    window.show();
    while let Some(e) = window.next() {

        if let Some(Button::Keyboard(key)) = e.press_args() {
            let mut pos = game.player.position.clone();
            let mut spr: Option<Tex> = None;          
            match key {
                Key::Up => { pos.y -= 1; spr = Some(Tex::from_path(&Path::new(
                        "./assets/player_n.png")).unwrap()); },
                Key::Down => { pos.y += 1; spr = Some(Tex::from_path(&Path::new(
                        "./assets/player_s.png")).unwrap()); },
                Key::Left => { pos.x -= 1; spr = Some(Tex::from_path(&Path::new(
                        "./assets/player_w.png")).unwrap()); },              
                Key::Right => { pos.x += 1; spr = Some(Tex::from_path(&Path::new(
                        "./assets/player_e.png")).unwrap()); },
                _ => (),
            }
            for elem in game.images.iter() {
                if pos.x == elem.position.x && pos.y == elem.position.y && elem.obj_type == ObjectType::Passing {
                    game.player.position = pos;

                    game.player.sprite = spr.clone().unwrap();

                }
            }
        }        
        if let Some(r) = e.render_args() {
            game.render(&r);       
        }
        if let Some(u) = e.update_args() {
            game.update(&u); 
        }
    }
}
```

Produces the error:

```
error: no method named `clone` found for type `std::option::Option<opengl_graphics::Texture>` in the current scope
   --> src/main.rs:159:46
159 |                     game.player.sprite = spr.clone().unwrap();
    |                                              ^^^^^
    |
    = note: the method `clone` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied: `opengl_graphics::Texture : std::clone::Clone`
```

I understand why I get this error, since `opengl_graphics::Texture` doesn't derive `Copy` I can't clone `Option<opengl_texture>`. What workaround is there for this?

I tried messing around with references but that didn't work.

Comment: How about using a `Rc<Tex>` instead of `Tex` directly?

Comment: @kennytm Should I make my temporary sprite 'spr' `Rc<Tex>`? I'm still a bit newbie to Rust so I never used `Rc` (seeing docs).

Comment: @DavidFrickert Unfortunately `game.player.sprite` needs to be `Rc<Tex>` as well, because there can only be one copy of plain `Tex`. Yeah once you go `Rc` it will be needed everywhere it touches.

Comment: @kennytm please add that as an answer! I think it nicely complements the one I just added.

Comment: @kennytm Thanks for the suggestion! It worked wonders!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How do I copy/clone a struct that derives neither?

You don't. The only thing you can do is take some kind of reference to it.

---

In this case, it is a very good thing that the library has chosen to not implement `Clone` or `Copy`. If you were able to clone the structure, you'd be allocating a lot of memory frequently and needlessly. Instead, the library has forced you to think about when you allocate that memory. One of the solutions is to load all the textures at application startup and reference them:

Change your structures to hold references:

```
#[derive(PartialEq)]
enum ObjectType {
    Blocking,
    Passing,
}

struct Object<'a> {
    sprite: &'a Tex,
    obj_type: ObjectType,
    position: Position,
}

struct Game<'a> {
    gl: GlGraphics,
    images: Vec<Object<'a>>,
    player: Player<'a>,
}

struct Player<'a> {
    sprite: &'a Tex,
    position: Position,
}

#[derive(Copy, Clone, PartialEq)]
struct Position {
    x: i32,
    y: i32,
}

struct Textures {
    player_n: Tex,
    player_s: Tex,
    player_e: Tex,
    player_w: Tex,
    wall: Tex,
    floor: Tex,
}
```

Load the textures early on in `main`. Note that there's no need to use `Path` explicitly, as it takes `AsRef<Path>`:

```
let textures = Textures {
    player_n: Tex::from_path("./assets/player_n.png").unwrap(),
    player_s: Tex::from_path("./assets/player_s.png").unwrap(),
    player_e: Tex::from_path("./assets/player_e.png").unwrap(),
    player_w: Tex::from_path("./assets/player_w.png").unwrap(),
    wall: Tex::from_path("./assets/wall.png").unwrap(),
    floor: Tex::from_path("./assets/floor.png").unwrap()
};
```

Then pass references to those textures:

```
match key {
    Key::Up => {
        pos.y -= 1;
        spr = Some(&textures.player_n)
    }
    Key::Down => {
        pos.y += 1;
        spr = Some(&textures.player_s)
    }
    Key::Left => {
        pos.x -= 1;
        spr = Some(&textures.player_w)
    }
    Key::Right => {
        pos.x += 1;
        spr = Some(&textures.player_e)
    }
    _ => (),
}
for elem in game.images.iter() {
    if pos == elem.position && elem.obj_type == ObjectType::Passing {
        game.player.position = pos;

        if let Some(spr) = spr {
            game.player.sprite = spr;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this also consolidates the places that errors can occur. There's no longer an `unwrap` inside the guts of the loop.

I was unable to get your code to finish compiling as the code is not complete but this should help get started:

```
error: no method named `render` found for type `Game<'_>` in the current scope
   --> src/main.rs:122:18
    |
122 |             game.render(&r);
    |                  ^^^^^^
    |
    = help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is implemented and in scope; the following trait defines an item `render`, perhaps you need to implement it:
    = help: candidate #1: `piston_window::RenderEvent`

error: no method named `update` found for type `Game<'_>` in the current scope
   --> src/main.rs:125:18
    |
125 |             game.update(&u);
    |                  ^^^^^^
    |
    = help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is implemented and in scope; the following traits define an item `update`, perhaps you need to implement one of them:
    = help: candidate #1: `piston_window::UpdateEvent`
    = help: candidate #2: `piston_window::<unnamed>::UpdateTexture`
    = help: candidate #3: `deflate::checksum::RollingChecksum`
    = help: candidate #4: `cocoa::appkit::NSOpenGLContext`
    = help: candidate #5: `cocoa::appkit::NSOpenGLContext`
```

---

In some cases, you may be able to wrap your types in an `Rc` or `Arc` and clone that. Cloning a `Rc`/`Arc` only increments a reference counter, regardless of the implementation of `Clone` for the underlying type (or the absence of such an implementation).

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! I've added the `impl Game` that missed. Meanwhile I'm messing around with `Rc` but I'm having some weird error, somehow `Path` is not finding my images anymore.

Comment: So, if you don't mind me asking, what would be more efficient: `Rc` or references? The way I applied `Rc<Tex>` involved cloning: `let mut spr: Rc<Tex> = game.player.sprite.clone()` and `game.player.sprite = spr.clone()`, but references don't need cloning so I would suppose references are better. Though I might be using `Rc` wrong.

Comment: By the way (I'm sorry I'm bothering you so much!), actually, I didn't create the `struct Position`, I think I got it included because of one of my `use`'s (i think `piston_window`. Can I create a `struct Position`and override the one included?

Comment: @DavidFrickert If you can manage your textures' lifetime, so that they live longer than the remaining parts of the program without leaking, then yes, keeping references will work. This will require adding some lifetime parameters and having a resource manager (something that will own the textures and only free them when appropriate), but should lead to better efficiency than `Rc`.